# MovieClips scale down when StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have my stage aligned to TOP_LEFT and scaled to StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER, the width and height of my SWF are :  width = 1920 and height = 1080.

The thing is when my i change the SWF size to bigger (height/width) the movieClips on the stage scale up and that's a good thing for me, but when i reduce the size of my SWF to smaller values (smaller than the default size), the movieClips get reduced as well, aren't they supposed to stay the same, if not is there a way to make that happen ?

Comment: Naturally, when you scale your swf up or down all objects within the movie will scale as well. Probably you could set the minWidth and minHeight of your main container so that it can't be scaled down below these values ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, how can i set the min width and height ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've misread the question and though we are talking about Flex and not pure ActionScript. I guess in this case the swf will just keep scaling depending on the StageScaleMode.

Comment: Oh thank you, so there is no way to prevent scale down only ?

Comment: @ZouhairElamraniAbouElassad, these are **[your options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html)**. You can get **[visual examples here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-stretch-your-swf-with-stagescalemode--active-4259)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the NO_BORDER scaleMode makes sure to not show the borders of the SWF and scale the center depending on the :

The ratios :

```
widthRatio = currentStageWidth/stageWidth
```

and

```
heightRatio = currentStageHeight/stageHeight.
```

The `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` are provided by AS3.

The `currentStageWidth` and `currentStageHeight` are supposed to be changing while resizing the browser window, the can be retrieved from the Flash Object (ie: `$("#flashObjectId").width()`).

Then we should compare the two ratios (`widthRatio` and `heightRatio`), the bigger  one has the scale value for the stage and the other elements on the stage.